# How to display part of information loaded with IMPORTXML function?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-formula

Here is my formula inserted in A1:

```
=importxml("http://www.goldforex.be/servlet/javaparser?pgm=lst_or_new&lg=fr","//tr[@valign='TOP']")
```

If you test this formula it will return numerous information. I would like to know how to display only information available from the Row 26 to Row 57 in Columns A and B.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the QUERY function to strip down the data as required.

`=QUERY(ImportXml("http://www.goldforex.be/servlet/javaparser?pgm=lst_or_new&lg=fr","//tr[@valign='TOP']");"select Col1, Col2 limit 31 label Col1 '', Col2 ''";26)`

The help page for the QUERY spreadsheet function has disappeared in recent times. You get a very basic explanation when searching for QUERY in the [function list](https://support.google.com/drive/table/25273?hl=en). The select clause uses the [GViz Query Language API](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage), although that article is not definitive when it comes to exactly what ou can and cannot use in the spreadsheet function select clause.

Comment: Hello AdamL thanks for your help and your lights. This sounds perfectly what I want to do but I'm affraid beacause it doesn't work. Do I need to preload a specific .js of something ?

Comment: Ok OK sory, this is working and I would like to thanks you a lot, one more question How to limit the result only for Col 1 and Col 3 very best regards and thanks again for your time.